# Laptop NIC dead but want to connect fast

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, ethernet, network-adapter

I have been using an old Acer Aspire 5250 laptop at home that I don't want to give up. When the NIC died I connected Ethernet via a USB adapter. But a speed test revealed that the USB 2.0 port & adapter are throttling my speed.

I have a few ideas I need help with:

1. Swap internal wifi b/g adapter with b/g/n pulled from another old laptop. Since WiFi can't connect directly to modem, replace current b/g router with cheap b/g/n from eBay.
2. Connect via Ethernet-USB & WiFi in parallel to improve overall speed.

Any guidance for me?

Comment: 3. Replace mobo with another compatible unit again probably from eBay.

Comment: How fast is your current internet connection (ie what speed can you get out of your ISP), and do you do much LAN file sharing?

Answer (score 1):

A decent Gigabit USB ->Ethernet adaptor should be able to provide well over 200 megabit/second on a USB 2.0 connection, and is probably the cheapest and fastest way to boost your speeds, assuming the bottleneck is not somewhere else.  (ie your USB->ethernet adaptor is not performing properly or you have a fault elsewhere).

USB2->Ethernet will be faster then 802.11n - and, in practice, faster then 802.11ac as well.

Connecting WIFI and Ethernet in parallel is hard, requires non-common hardware and software to support it, and will still suffer from packets arriving out of order - in short, its probably not worth doing.  (Its not impossible, just hard)

Swapping B/G for B/G/N could be a viable alternative, although you might want to consider looking at stuff which supports AC.  AC stuff will work in both the 2.4 and 5gig bands, and will give you greater range and throughput.

I do note that your laptop is really past its use-by date, and, save for nostalgia purposes you would be better off spending money replacing your laptop (even a second hand one) - the CPU in your system is a similar speed to a Pentium 4.  Indeed, while the performance issue may be the USB port, I wonder if, in fact, its the fact that the CPU can't keep up with the additional overhead of the USB adaptor.